# Proposition to add a tag for "high refresh rate"

Tags: discussion, retag-request

I searched for questions about high refresh rate displays and I found that they mostly use the general tag for [refresh-rate](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/refresh-rate). I think it makes sense to subdivide it further into questions about 60hz+ rate monitors under [high-refresh-rate](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/high-refresh-rate) tag or something.

Answer (score 7):

No.

refresh-rate is good enough to cover the questions currently there. And there are only under 80 questions using it.

Plus refresh-rate is not as intuitive as high-refresh-rate, and only adds to splitting it up for the sake of splitting it up.

Comment: Well, it *is* about splitting up. I wanted to find all questions that deal with >60hz monitors, and instead I get all of them, even unrelated to what I'm looking for. Why is this not a good reason?

Comment: @user1306322, when you search, you can exclude things you don't want.  If a lot of the undesired hits specifically mention 60hz, you could exclude that to improve the result (even exclude multiple terms).  You can also try adding words like "high" or "high refresh rate" to the search, which might help enrich the results.

Comment: @fixer1234 seems like it could be much more easily fixed by adding a tag for framerates above 60Hz in my opinion